# How do I check if a number is positive or negative in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I check if a number is positive or negative in C#?

Comment: Useful Question.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

```
bool positive = number > 0;
bool negative = number < 0;
```

Comment: What about poor old negative zero?!

Comment: By definition, zero is not positive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(number)

Comment: @SimonFischer There are definitely branches of mathematics, computer science, also regular science which use a negative and positive zero. Chemists and physicists for example will sometimes use -0 for a number which was negative and rounded to zero. Definitions only have meaning within a context. When you treat the mathematical definitions you were taught as though they are truly universal you risk ending up in a different mathematical context where you are wrong.

Answer (score 189):

Of course no-one's actually given the correct answer,

```
num != 0   // num is positive *or* negative!
```

Comment: no, OP asked if   `is positive or is negative` not `is (positive or negative)`

Comment: 0 still positive

Answer (score 94):

OVERKILL!

```
public static class AwesomeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsPositive(this int number)
    {
        return number > 0;
    }

    public static bool IsNegative(this int number)
    {
        return number < 0;
    }

    public static bool IsZero(this int number)
    {
        return number == 0;
    }

    public static bool IsAwesome(this int number)
    {
        return IsNegative(number) && IsPositive(number) && IsZero(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Internally, it should instantiate a class which implements `ISignDeterminator` using a `SignDeterminatorFactory`.

Comment: Incomplete: you should check for IsNaN() as well ;)

Comment: @slashmais: On an `int`?! What magical land of C# are you working in?

Comment: For .NET 4.0 you should add `IsImaginary`.

Comment: You can also use System.Data.OracleClient to connect to an Oracle database and execute PL/SQL to determine if a number is negative.

Comment: You should add <summary> commentary in your code so it becomes more reliable, consistent, decent, accessable, stable, robust, solid, safe and clear.

Comment: check for -ve / +ve decimals as well

Comment: awesome IsAwesome method xD

Answer (score 65):

The [Math.Sign method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkkxx1x2.aspx) is one way to go. It will return -1 for negative numbers, 1 for positive numbers, and 0 for values equal to zero (i.e. zero has no sign). Double and single precision variables will cause an exception ([ArithmeticException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arithmeticexception.aspx)) to be thrown if they equal NaN.

Comment: Wow didn't know this exists.What happens for NaN?

Comment: @Tanmoy: Looks like it will throw [an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arithmeticexception.aspx) in that case.

Comment: But then he has to check if the result of Math.Sign is positive or negative too! Does he use Math.Sign for that as well? ;)

Comment: @AndyC: I enjoyed the humor, but he should be doing equality comparison against the return value of `Math.Sign` (since it explicitly defines possible return values.)

Comment: I didn't expect to find a useful answer below this question, but this is actually what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 56):

```
num < 0 // number is negative
```

Comment: I assume that this is a beginner, which we should try to help.  Once you learn the right way -- check this for the wrong way http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/When_(n_0x3c_0)_won_0x27_t_do_0x2e_.aspx

Answer (score 22):

This is the industry standard:

```
int is_negative(float num)
{
  char *p = (char*) malloc(20);
  sprintf(p, "%f", num);
  return p[0] == '-';
}
```

Comment: This is not C# though

Comment: I tried it out. My program ran eventually out of memory. Could there be a leak in your code?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann there was indeed a memory leak, as `p` was `malloc()`'d but never `free()`'d. I fixed this in my edit.

Comment: @Will, well done for spotting this very obscure leak! Though I frown upon you changing the meaning of the original poster's introductory sentence. I still believe it's correct to call this the industry standard. Hence, to keep with the spirit of this answer, and with respect to the original poster, I've reverted your edit, okay?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Then the right solution was to correct the post to use the original sentence and the fixed code. With respect to the original poster, anyone who stumbles across this will experience rampant memory leaking. It appears from the comments above that you ran into this leak yourself. I don't think "the industry standard" has memory leaks, and I coudn't find anything to back up this being an industry standard. But I'll leave it and fix the code.

Comment: @Will, do I really need to state the obvious about the original post and my comments, which got upvotes while yours doesn't? (Spoiler: it has to do with sarcasm, and yours doesn't, which means you've killed the joke that bad existed here - or do you really think that this answer was meant to be taken seriously??)

Comment: I took it seriously; the sarcasm was non-obvious and this will confuse new users and non-native speakers. If it's not a serious answer, I'll just revert my edit and flag it as not an answer.

Comment: There we go, reverted, flagged, and downvoted. I wasn't aware this was a joke.

Answer (score 20):

You youngins and your fancy less-than signs.

Back in my day we had to use `Math.abs(num) != num //number is negative` !

Comment: (If it wasn't obvious, this was intended to be humor)

Comment: @Eric: No, because it will throw an `OverflowException` if `num` is `MinValue` for whatever type is passed in (`Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`).  Results are even worse for floating point values, where they could also be `NaN`, since `NaN != NaN`.

Answer (score 11):

```
    public static bool IsPositive<T>(T value)
        where T : struct, IComparable<T>
    {
        return value.CompareTo(default(T)) > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Native programmer's version. Behaviour is correct for little-endian systems.

```
bool IsPositive(int number)
{
   bool result = false;
   IntPtr memory = IntPtr.Zero;
   try
   {
       memory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
       if (memory == IntPtr.Zero)
           throw new OutOfMemoryException();

       Marshal.WriteInt32(memory, number);

       result = (Marshal.ReadByte(memory, 3) & 0x80) == 0;
   }
   finally
   {
       if (memory != IntPtr.Zero)
           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memory);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Do not ever use this.

Comment: "Do not ever use this"? But it's enterprise-quality code, perfect for enterprise software! You're missing `IsPositiveChecker`, `IsPositiveCheckerInterface`, `IsPositiveCheckerFactory`, and `IsPositiveCheckerFactoryInterface`, though.

Comment: Just used this in my Hello World console app. 10/10 would do it again.

Comment: you are missing a set of parenthesis as '&' has a lower precedence than '==', so you should have `result = (Marshal.ReadByte(memory, 3) & 0x80) == 0;` instead. Also, you should have a `return result;` somewhere in there at the end so it will actually return the result.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (num < 0) {
  //negative
}
if (num > 0) {
  //positive
}
if (num == 0) {
  //neither positive or negative,
}
```

or use "else ifs"

Answer (score 7):

You just have to compare if the value & its absolute value are equal:

```
if (value == Math.abs(value))
    return "Positif"
else return "Negatif"
```

Comment: It will break for the edge case scenario. For example for int: Int32.MinValue: -2147483648.

Answer (score 6):

For a 32-bit signed integer, such as `System.Int32`, aka `int` in C#:

```
bool isNegative = (num & (1 << 31)) != 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static bool IsNegative<T>(T value)
   where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    return value.CompareTo(default(T)) < 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
bool isNegative(int n) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= Int32.MaxValue; i++) {
    if (n == i) 
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int j = num * -1;

if (j - num  == j)
{
     // Num is equal to zero
}
else if (j < i)
{
      // Num is positive
}
else if (j > i) 
{
     // Num is negative
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code takes advantage of SIMD instructions to improve performance.

```
public static bool IsPositive(int n)
{
  var v = new Vector<int>(n);
  var result = Vector.GreaterThanAll(v, Vector<int>.Zero);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First parameter is stored in EAX register and result also.

```
function IsNegative(ANum: Integer): LongBool; assembler;
asm
   and eax, $80000000
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

## March 2023 update:

```
int.IsPositive(-1) // false
int.IsNegative(-1) // true
```

No extension methods (like the answers above suggest) or extra code needed.

[int.IsPositive(int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.ispositive?view=net-7.0), [int.IsNegative(int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.isnegative?view=net-7.0).

---

P.S. It is very unfortunate that these methods are static. If numbers in C# were objects as in Ruby, it would be just `1.positive?`, i.e. without any static methods.