# Trying to stop function on return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, return

I'm using the jQuery Validator plugin with jQuery 1.6.2.

I'm not validating a `<form>` but only a lone field by itself.  This is because there are several unique `<form>`'s on this one page and the value from this one field is shared, copied, etc.

The `success` and `invalidHandler` handlers are both working correctly based on my rules.

```
var myValidate = function() {
    $("#field").validate({

        // rules, message, etc.

       success: function(error){
          //  doing all kinds of things if this validates
          return true;
       },
       invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
          //  what to do if this fails validation
          return false;
       },
    });         
};
```

And I have several other functions unrelated to each other that simply call the `myValidate` function above...

```
$('#myElement1').click(function() {
    myValidate;  // call to "myValidate" to validate field
    // doing stuff here only if "myValidate" returns true.
});

$('#myElement2').click(function() {
    myValidate;  // call to "myValidate" to validate field
    // only do other things here if "myValidate" returns true.
});

$('#myElement3').click(function() {
    myValidate;  // call to "myValidate" to validate field
    // and different things to do here only if "myValidate" returns true.
});
```

The above is a very basic representation of what I'm doing and there are no errors.

All this is working except for one thing... my brain.  I cannot seem to figure out how to stop/continue the flow of the secondary function(s) that are calling `myValidate` based on the `return true` or `false` within `myValidate`.

The way I have it, whether it returns true or false, everything still executes.

Can anyone kindly explain what I have done wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you need to catch the event and do a preventDefault()?

Comment: @KevinMcTigue, I'm not trying to stop the default action of an event.  I'm trying to halt subsequent lines in my other functions depending on results from `myValidate` function.

Comment: `myValidate` doesn't really return anything directly it seems, it only indirectly fires callbacks, which may return something (but not to the caller of `myValidate`). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @deceze, you're not missing anything.  I made a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I posted the question, I was not thinking very clearly about the whole thing at all.  Besides the wrong approach, there were a couple mistakes preventing it from doing what I wanted.

**Side Issue #1** - I was trying to validate this text field "on blur" so I had a whole separate event & function, which led to my unconventional approach and stupid question.  All un-needed.  All I needed was `onkeyup`, it validates as you type out the text.  No form "submit" required.

```
onkeyup: function(element) { this.element(element); }
```

**Side Issue #2** - I was looking for something that was the opposite of the `success:` handler, something which fires off whenever validation has failed.  However, `invalidHandler:` only fires when the `form` is submitted.  Even though I ultimately put my field inside a generic form, the form does not need a "submit" in order for validation to take place.  I finally realized that the `errorPlacement:` handler fires off whenever the form fails validation, exactly opposite of the `success` handler... this is perfect.  You don't have to "submit" anything to validate, and the text is validated as you type... it's built into the module.

**Side Issue #3** - This issue was only on the SO posting and not my project.  Target of validation must be a `<form>`, **not** an `<input>` field.  Not only did I neglect to mention that fact, I stated the opposite.  It should have been like this, `$("#form").validate();`

**Issue #4** - And obviously, I was incorrectly creating and referencing the `myValidate` function.  I removed all that and just left `$('#form').validate();` out by itself.  <s>Now that I have a flag being set/unset on valid/invalid</s> Now that I'm using the `.valid()` method, I can perform my other functions using a simple "if/then".

**Solution:**

So originally, to solve the problem, I ultimately used a flag variable with some "if/then" statements which is only what I was thinking to avoid when I posted the question... at least that's what I was thinking at the time.  Maybe there's a more elegant solution...

**EDIT:** Yes, there is a more elegant solution...

After looking into Greg's answer, I figure out how to use the [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) method instead...

[<s>previous jsFiddle using a flag variable</s>](http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/9fgVN/7/)

[new jsFiddle using `.valid()` method as below](http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/9fgVN/8/)

```
$("#form").validate({
    onkeyup: function(element) { this.element(element); },
    validClass: 'valid',
    rules: {
        comments: {
            required: false,
            maxlength: 180
        }
    },
    success: function(error){
        // stuff to do when it's valid (does not require form submit)
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        // stuff to do when it's not valid (does not require form submit)
    }
});
```

And then several similar functions are attached to various other events.  The "if/then" checks <s>for the validation flag</s> the `.valid()` method before executing anything.

```
$('#myElement1').click(function() {
    if($("#form").valid()){ // if validated
        // doing stuff here only if it was already validated
    };
});

$('#myElement2').click(function() {
    if($("#form").valid()){ // if validated
        // doing stuff here only if it was already validated
    };
});
```

So why am I doing all this?

As stated in my original question, I am sharing the content of this one text field with several other forms on the page.  They must be validated too, but this time I'm using the `submitHandler:` since these other forms actually get "submitted".

This methodology allows me to to sort-of "nest" the validation of the lone field (in `#form`) within the validation of the other forms being submitted (#formTWO & #formThree)...

```
$("#formTWO").validate({
    // rules for #formTWO
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        copyText();  // copy text from #form into #formTWO hidden field before submission
        if($("#form").valid()){ // only allow #formTWO to submit if #form is valid
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});

$("#formThree").validate({
    // rules for #formThree
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        copyText();  // copy text from #form into #formThree hidden field before submission
        if($("#form").valid()){ // only allow #formThree to submit if #form is valid
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup, mate. Well explained. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

I would structure your code to follow modern async patterns. Perhaps structure your code so that a call to myValidate would look like this...

```
$('#myElement1').click(function() {
  myValidate(function(result) {
    if (result === true) {
      //must be valid!
    } else {
      //invalid
    }
  }
});
```

Here's how I would structure the myValidate function.

```
var myValidate = function(callback) {
    $("#field").validate({

        // rules, message, etc.

       success: function(error){
          //  doing all kinds of things if this validates
          return callback(true);
       },
       invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
          //  what to do if this fails validation
          return callback(false);
       }
    });         
};
```

Comment: I think I'm going about this all wrong.  I'm trying to validate a single field from multiple events.  Click here, validate field.  Blur there, validate same field.  Select checkbox, validate same field yet again.  This is stupid because all I really need is a more bullet-proof way to validate a text area after typing into it.  I started with a `blur()` but that would fail if you didn't click anyplace before submitting the form.  It's not as simple as it sounds because the field is outside the scope of the `form` element and submit button.

Comment: Okay, I edited it a bit. You could simply define 1 function that handles all of the events you want.

Comment: It looks good to me but for some reason it's not working.  I'll provide more details after I troubleshoot a bit.

Comment: Likely, I'm going to take an entirely different approach to the one field and just delete this whole question.  I've posted too many mistakes here for it to be nothing but confusing.   Anyway, here is your solution in a Fiddle and it's not working at all... I'm sure it's not you but the methodology. http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/9fgVN/1/

Comment: Alright, I found the problem. You had $("#comments").validate but it should be $("#myForm").validate

Here's the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/9fgVN/3/

Comment: I had lots of problems with this stupid thing.  I scrapped it all and started from scratch.   I'll be posting a final answer/solution tomorrow if I don't delete this whole thread first.  For starters, `invalidHandler` is supposed to be called on "form submission".  Since I'm not "submitting" anything but merely validating a field on some event, that part was all wrong.  I really appreciate your help (+1) but now I'm really sorry to have started this whole thread.

Comment: **Thanks again for all your help!**  In my posted answer, I included a comprehensive explanation of all the various issues both in my project and in my OP.  There's also a solution and fiddle of what I ended up doing.  Maybe there's some cleaner way than using a flag variable but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try restructuring your code a bit. You need to call the `$().valid()` method to determine if it is valid, not from handlers inside the `.validate()` options.

Also note that I couldn't get it to work without wrapping the input in a `<form>` tag.

Here is my attempt at restructuring it, demonstrated in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/UYPDe/):

```
$(function() {
    // set up the validation
    $("#field").validate();

    // define your click handlers
    $('#myElement1').click(function() {
        if (myValidate()) {
            alert('Click 1: Validate passed.');
        } else {
            alert('Click 1: Validate failed.');
        }
    });

    $('#myElement2').click(function() {
        if (myValidate()) {
            alert('Click 2: Validate passed.');
        } else {
            alert('Click 2: Validate failed.');
        }
    });

    $('#myElement3').click(function() {
        if (myValidate()) {
            alert('Click 3: Validate passed.');
        } else {
            alert('Click 3: Validate failed.');
        }
    });
});

// put your function down here
function myValidate() {
    var isValid = $('#field').valid();
    if (isValid) {
            //  doing all kinds of things if this validates
            $('#feedback').text('Validation passed.');
    } else {
            //  what to do if this fails validation
            $('#feedback').text('Validation failed.');        
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank-you for your efforts.  The original concept had lots of unrelated issues.  I ended up re-working the whole thing and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`myValidate;` does not call `myValidate`. It merely references it.

You want an `if` statement.

```
if (myValidate()) {
    // Valid
}
```

```
if (!myValidate()) {
    // Not valid
}
```

This is basic JavaScript (basic *programming*); if you aren't familiar with this, please try learning more about programming and JavaScript.

You can also pass arguments to make it work with multiple forms.

Comment: I think it's unfair to lecture someone to learn more about programming and JavaScript while they're trying to learn more about programming and JavaScript. I'm so sick of SO know-it-alls. You, too, were once a terrible programmer. Now you're just a jerk.

Comment: "myValidate; does not call myValidate. It merely references it."

I noticed that too, but I thought he may have just forgotten the ()'s

Comment: **Quote:**  _"please try learning more about programming and JavaScript."_  Geesh... isn't that why most people are here, to try & learn more?  Yes, obviously it's basic stuff... as explained within my question, I acknowledged I was simply stuck on something basic.  After seeing your answer, it clicked.  There's no need to make belittling comments within your answer... as you can see by my SO rep, I've correctly answered a few questions.

Comment: Yeah, modern JS engines are pretty lenient. Just for future reference though, remember that funcName() (invoking) is indeed different than funcName; (referencing)

Comment: @Sparky672: I was not meaning to offend; I'm merely stating fact: for people who don't know much about programming, learning from places intended to help you learn will be a lot more effective than asking questions here. I didn't observe your rep this time or I wouldn't have put it quite this way, but I still remain entirely surprised that you not recognise the `if` statement as what you need.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, ***this is a place intended to help you learn***, what the hell do you think it is?

Comment: @Chris, I guess you never had a day when you worked so long you couldn't see straight?  I've been programming in various languages since 1981 and JavaScript since 1998... and today my brain simply failed me from lack of food & sleep.  I am not so proud that I can't come to SO to ask for a little push back into line.  Just please refrain from making so many assumptions about my level of education based on a stupid question.

Comment: @Sparky672: no, I haven't. I guess this is in the same sort of category as [How do I check if a number is positive or negative in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099366/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-positive-or-negative-in-c), then?

Comment: @eyelidlessness: Stack Overflow is a place to help you learn, yes; I meant to specify "learn a language"; Stack Overflow isn't here explicitly to teach individuals JavaScript.

Comment: @Chris:  And that's obviously not why I'm here, geesh... 3500 rep earned mainly in the jQuery category.  This is the last time I'm going to say this was obviously a dumb question.  Some day you'll ask one too.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, you're right. It's a language-agnostic site. The tag system helps distinguish posts on different languages. So it's not a site specifically to help people learn JS, JS is a subset of what it's here to help people learn. I'm not sure what your point is, other than to stammer and avoid admitting that you were rude and it was unwarranted.