# HTML Button needing double click (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, button, click, submit, double

I'm facing a issue with a html button that opens a jQuery popup, It requires 2 clicks before it actually opens,

The jquery code is:

```
$(\'#RequestSupport2\').submit(function() {
    var values = {};
    $("#RequestSupport2 :checked").each(function(key, value) {  
        values["check["+key+"]"] = $(this).val();
    });
    var values2 = $.param(values);

    $("#requestsupport").colorbox({href:"URLdetail.php?action=request_support&"+values2});
    return false;
});
    });
```

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried .click instead of .submit?

Comment: When i use .click it doesn't allow me to check all the options before submitting the form (The form contains checkboxs which is then submited to the colorbox)

Comment: you could set some sort of validation flag and if the criteria is met then use  the sumbit event.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you use the jQuery Validation plugin, [you do not actually have to "submit" the form in order to do validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815624/trying-to-stop-function-on-return-false/7845033#7845033).  So you'd never have to block submission with a `preventDefault()` or a `return false`.

Comment: The idea is that the form submits (has different checkboxs) and opens results in the the colorbox

Answer (score 1):

Try the click event:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault() })
```

This will prevent the submission of the form...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues at a glance. Why have you used escape characters in the initial selector? Use `$('#RequestSupport2')` instead of `$(\'#RequestSupport2\')`. And Emmanuel N is correct. Submit is a form event, not a button event. Ensure your button with ID RequestSupport2 is of type button not submit (unless your intention is to post the form in the absense of Javascript), then use jQuery to handle the click event. You could also try `$("input:checked", "#RequestSupport2")` instead of `$("#RequestSupport2 :checked")`. If none of this helps I'm stumped.

Comment: Hi, The button id is RequestSupport2, We're using escape characters because it begins with echo ',,,, We've tried what you mentioned and that didn't work, The idea is that the form submits and opens in the the colorbox