# How to check if a boxed numeric value is negative?

Tags: c#

Hmm, this may seems a simple question, but I would like to know the fastest way.

I have an object which is a boxed number, I don't know is it `double`, `int`, or some numeric type. I want to check if the boxed value is negative.

I use this conversion but I am not sure if it is as fast as can be:

```
private bool CheckNegative(object number)
{
   return System.Convert.ToDouble(number) < 0;
}
```

Arsen

Comment: Why do you need this code in the first place? This looks like a bad software design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a number is positive or negative in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099366/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-positive-or-negative-in-c)

Comment: @GarrettVlieger: Obviously not a dupe, the number is boxed here.

Comment: If you need it to be fast, know the type of the value.

Comment: Question : How did u get that much points without knowing such a simple solution ? Use Baseclass 'Number' and check if your object is derived of this

Comment: I am sure there isn't any such class called Number that double, int, etc derives from.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.operators.compareobjectless.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." - that probably means it might disappear without notice in any future version.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it is WPV convertion method, I need to check hilight negative values, I want to use this converter for all numeric types, I don't think it is bad design result here..

Comment: @ArsenMkrt I have to admit that I don’t know what WPV is but since this code completely subverts type checking I can say that in almost all situations it’s bad code. If you want to compare arbitrary objects, use the (generic!) `IComparable` or `IComparer` interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for advice @KonradRudolph, here is wpf converter interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx, I think it is better to have one converter for all numeric types than to write for each type...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the only way to do it.

But if you wanted to avoid writing multiple functions that take double, int, float, etc to check for negative number, I would redirect you to following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/828820/150830

Answer (score 5):

Use the C# version 4 *dynamic* keyword here to take advantage of its dynamic operator binding:

```
private static bool CheckNegative(dynamic number)
{
   return number < 0;
}
```

Works fine on boxed value types as well.

Comment: I like this way, but dynamics are so dirty :)

Comment: @ArsenMkrt It’s not a bit dirtier than using `object`.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that this *might* be faster because it cuts to the chase and does not need to convert integral types to IEEE floating point:

```
bool CheckNegative(object number)
{
    switch(Type.GetTypeCode(number.GetType())) {
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            return (int)number < 0;
        case TypeCode.Single:
            return (float)number < 0;
        // etc etc
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

It won't be pretty though.

**Update:** [Turns out](http://ideone.com/IrOqL) this approach is slightly *slower*, except when dealing with `decimal`. So the best practical decision seems to be keep `Convert.ToDouble`.

Answer (score -4):

```
object bla = 2343;

if ( bla is Number )
{
     bool t = (Number)bla > 0;
}
```

Comment: System.Number ... since .net 1.0 ?!