# Code for identifying negative and positive even/odd number not working

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to write a code that tells me whether a number is negative/positive, even/odd. For example:

- given `-2` -> `e -1`,
- given `-3` -> `o -1`

and so on. The thing is it's working for everything expect negative odd numbers.

Here's the part of the code that's responsible for deciding:

```
if (number % 2 == 0 && number < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("e" + " " + "-1");
}
else if (number % 2 == 0 && number > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("e" + " " + "1");
}
else if (number % 2 == 1 && number > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("o" + " " + "1");
}
else if (number % 2 == 1 && number < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("o" + " " + "-1");
}
else if (number == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("0");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a number is positive or negative in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099366/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-positive-or-negative-in-c) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818680/testing-if-a-list-of-integer-is-odd-or-even both have information pertaining to your issue.

Comment: `if (number == 0) Console.WriteLine("0") else Console.WriteLine($"{(number % 2 == 0 ? 'e' : 'o')} {(number < 0 ? -1 : 1)}")`

Answer (score 0):

if it is a negative no. it's remainder is going to be negative as well when divided by 2 so :

```
else if (number % 2 == -1 && number < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("o" + " " + "-1");
}
```

or directly

```
else if (number % 2 == -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remainder computation can vary. In math when we compute

```
  r = a mod b
```

we, usually, assume that `r` in `[0 .. |b|)` range, i.e. `r` is *non negative*. However, in case of modulo arithmetics we can add `k * |b|` (where `k` is arbitrary integer) term. For instance

```
 -5 mod 3 == -8, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7 etc.
                      ^  ^
              C# choice  |
                         Typical math choice: r in [0 .. 3) range
```

In case of **c#** implementation we have `-2`, not `1`. So the safe method to test for being odd / even is to compare with `0`, not `-1`, `1`:

```
 if (number == 0) 
   Console.WriteLine("0"); // 0 - special case 
 else 
   Console.WriteLine($"{(number % 2 == 0 ? 'e' : 'o')} {(number < 0 ? -1 : 1)}");
```

Please, note `number % 2 == 0` test bor being *even / odd*